# $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} 1^x$

Tags: limits, infinity

Why is $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} 1^x = 1$?

Why can $1^x$ be written as just $1$ when using $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}$ and how come this does not work for $2^x$ or $3^x$ as $x\to\infty$?

Comment: I think you should just use the definition. For finite limits the limit is nothing else then the accumulation point!

Comment: For all $x \in \Bbb R$, $1^x=1$, right, i.e. the limit is 1. However, $2^x>2$ for all $x > 1$, i.e. $\lim_{x \to \infty} 2^x\neq 2$.

Comment: @Extended Thinking of the first limit as the result of _infinitely many multiplications_ is wrong.  Trying to perform   "infinitely many operations" will lead to many false conclusions. Limits were invented to get around those problems.

Comment: Yeah you're right, but for $1^=1$ for all x real, so 1 can be represented as an infinite product of ones.

Answer (score 4):

$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, $1^x=1$

therefore the function $h(x)=1^x$ is constant and its value is $1$, so is the limit.

$h(x)=2^x$ is not a constant function.